# Is it possible to send PHP session variables across domains through cURL?

Tags: php, session, curl, cross-domain

If a person logs into a website (**Website A**) and this website creates session variables, could another website (**Website B**) make a cURL call to a PHP routine on **Website A** that would send back to **Website B** a json variable with **Website A**'s session variables?

If so, how can I accomplish this?

This is the scenario I have in mind:

1. User visits **Website A** and logs in. This create session variables in **Website B**
2. In the same browser session, the user visits **Website B**.
3. The homepage in **Website B** makes a cURL call to a specific routine in **Website A** that verifies if session variables exist and, if so, send their information back as JSon.
4. Depending on the JSon variable content (if it exists), **Website B** shows the user a different content.

Is it doable through cURL?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried it? What's the problem?

Comment: The problem I had was that the session variables returned empty. Using the same solution through redirect, i.e., header(location:...), worked. In other words, in the same browser session, cURL gave me empty session variables, but double redirect (forth and back) gave me the session variables as they exist.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this so I have no idea if it would work however my best guess to get something similar to what you'd want is as follows.

Assuming both websites are on the same server you could manually set the session_id() and then keep track of this value. You then send this ID string to Website B and call session_id() there too with the same ID.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

If your Websites aren't on the same servers then you'd need to edit your php.ini and connect your session store to a service like memcache.

So for example.

Website A:

```
session_id('test');
$_SESSION['hello'] = "hello world\n";
```

Website B:

```
session_id('test');
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
```

Obviously you'd need to do a lot more work than above as you need to generate unique IDs for each user / request.

Answer (score 1):

As my websites are **NOT** in the same server, this is what I had to do to make it work (without *memcache*). This is not the most elegant solution but this is how I made it work, i.e., how to send to **Website A** the contents of the session variables of **Website B**:

1. A php routine in **Website A** redirects using [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to **Website B**. The requesting php in **Website A** sends its URL as part of the *query string* so **Website B** knows where to send its answer.
2. The receiving page in **Website B** grabs the ***session ID*** using [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) and sends it back to **Website A** through an auto-submit post form.
3. Now with the **session ID** from **Website B**, **Website A** makes a cURL call to **Website B**, which returns the content of the session variables of **Website B**.

**Note**: without the ***session ID***, **Website B** sends an empty session variable to **Website A**.